# regarding transforming PNG into JPG

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, png

I have a set of `PNG` files which are of shape `(64,64,4)`, and want to feed it to a `tensorflow` model which was designed for `JPG` files, which has shape `(64,64,3)`. I plan to transform `PNG` into `JPG`, is this a good approach, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: ummm sure? ... I guess?

Comment: The ImageMagick utility `convert` will do this pretty trivially: `convert file.png file.jpg`.

Comment: But how to convert a collection of png files stored in a single folder to another set of jpg files stored in a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way transforming it would be using `opencv`, not sure about the side-effects, you might get a little amount of color shifting. This will take all the `png's` in the current folder and save them as `jpgs`

```
from glob import glob                                                           
import cv2 
pngs = glob('./*.png')

for png in pngs:
    img = cv2.imread(png)
    cv2.imwrite(png[:-3] + 'jpg', img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
```